# What's the best way to filter/validate ID's in a '#show' action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, routes

So, this is really a Rails pattern question.

I have a Rails 3.0.9 application that works, and well. We're using Airbrake to detect and report errors, and that's helped tune the last few leaks in the program design.

Only, now it gets attacked by robots (Google, crawlers, etc) with bad input.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: 
"google_ads_dbg" LINE 1: ....message_thread_id WHERE "message_threads"."id" = 
'google_ad... ^ : SELECT "message_threads".* FROM "message_threads" INNER JOIN    
"message_thread_users" ON "message_threads".id = "message_thread_users".message_thread_id 
WHERE "message_threads"."id" = 'google_ads_dbg' AND (("message_thread_users".user_id = 
33899)) LIMIT 1
```

The restful routes:

```
resource :inbox do
  resources :messages
end
```

The first line of the MessagesController#show

```
@message_thread = current_user.message_threads.find(params[:id])
```

Do I prefix every `.find params[:id]` call to validate the integer-ness of the input? Do I tack-on `:constraints => {:id => /[0-9]+/}` to every `resource` line in my routes.rb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the constraints for multiple resources at once.

```
scope :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ } do
  resources :inbox do
    resources :messages
  end
end
```

This makes most sense to me. You could validate the integer in before-filters in your controllers, but I think that's a messy alternative given your situation.

Comment: This makes so much sense, I forgot about routing scopes :)

Comment: The follow up question is: Is my problem with bad input so uncommon that this solution isn't part of the common routing pattern?
It seems essential to site security and stability.